# Avoidance of less-than-or-equal-to operator in java.lang.Character

Tags: java, comparison-operators

In Character.java of the java.lang package (Oracle JDK 8),

```
public static final int MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT = 0x010000;
public static final int MAX_CODE_POINT = 0X10FFFF;

public static boolean isSupplementaryCodePoint(int codePoint) {
    return codePoint >= MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT
        && codePoint <  MAX_CODE_POINT + 1;
}
```

why did the author(s) choose to add one to MAX_CODE_POINT and then compare the result to codePoint using the **<** operator?

Why not just do the following, where the "<=" operator is used:

```
 public static boolean isSupplementaryCodePoint(int codePoint) {
    return codePoint >= MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT
        && codePoint <=  MAX_CODE_POINT;
}
```

There are other examples in the same file like this, where one is being added to the right-hand operand and then the less-than operator is used to do the comparison. Is it being done this way for performance reasons? Can someone explain the original reasoning? And why isn't it being done for the **<=** operator but not the **>=** operator? How relevant is the reasoning today?

Comment: who is the author, then we can go and ask him.

Comment: Scary, the authors listed in java.lang.Character (Oracle JDK 8) are listed as:  Lee Boynton, Guy Steele, Akira Tanaka, Martin Buchholz and Ulf Zibis

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, Java uses half-open intervals in a lot of situations--that is, intervals where a number is `>=` the lower bound (i.e. *inclusive*) and `<` the upper bound (i.e. *exclusive*).  See, for example, the definitions of `substring()` and `binarySearch` in `Arrays`.  It corresponds to how `for` loops are usually written: `for (int i = lower-bound; i < upper-bound; i++)`, which looks at the same kind of half-open interval from `lower-bound` to `upper-bound`.  The author may have been just following that pattern.  There's no performance difference either way.